# Selenium Test Script opening browser instance for each TC

Tags: java, selenium, browser

My selenium script is opening 2 chrome browsers when I run the 2 tests , How can we have one browser execute all the Test Scripts?
I have a Configtest.java which basically opens the `ChromeDriver`

```
public class Configtest   {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "..\\chromedriver.exe");
       driver = new ChromeDriver();

    }
}


public class LogScreenTest extends Configtest {
@Test
public void login() {
 // use the driver defined in Configtest
}

public class HomeTest extends Configtest {
@Test
public void homeTest() {
// use the driver defined in Configtest
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Hooks. In The @BeforeTestCase hook open the session

```
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And close the active session in a @AfterTestCase hook

```
    if(driver!=null){driver.qui()}
```

Comment: does that mean we are closing the browser session that is opened in LogScreenTest  and again open a new one for HomeTest ? If so, I cannot keep login into application everytime a script should be run, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: An alternative will be to check whether or not the driver session is already created in your setUp. If so just return the same driver . if(driver!=null) return driver else return new ChromeDriver()